# Using coverage to test python program

Tags: python, code-coverage, coverage.py

I'm using https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-4.4.1/ to determine how much of a Python program I'm using.

However, when I use command line:

```
$coverage myprogram.py
```

It runs the program in `Python 2` and my program only works in `Python 3`.  I can't figure out how to get coverage to use `Python 3`. Also my command line is set up to use `Python 3`.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the

```
alias pip='pip3'
```

Then I had to install coverage3 and that did the trick.